# Group representation scalar product

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ be a finite dimensional complex representation of the group $G$. Show that there is an inner product on $V$ such that $G$ acts by unitary matrices.

My approach so far was to define the sought after inner product as follows:

$\sum\nolimits_{g \in G} < \rho(g) u, \rho(g) v>$ where $u,v \in V$, and $<,>$ is the standard scalar product on $V$. I need to show that this equals $\sum\nolimits_{g \in G} <u,v> = |G|<u,v>$ where $|G|$ is the cardinality of $G$. 
This is where I'm stuck and I don't know how to show that the left sight equals the right side. Anyone got a hint for me?

Cheers!

Comment: You cannot show $\langle u,v\rangle_G:=\sum_{g\in G}\langle\rho(g)u,\rho(g)v\rangle$ is equal to $\sum_{g\in G}\langle u,v\rangle=|G|\langle u,v\rangle$, because in general this is false (unless I misunderstand what you mean by "standard scalar product on $V$"). However, it is true that $\sum_{g\in G}\langle\rho(g)u,\rho(g)v\rangle_G=|G|\langle u,v\rangle_G$, where the $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_G$'s are *already* averaged inner products, and this would indeed lead to $G$ acting unitarily. However it is better to just check $\langle\rho(h)u,\rho(h)v\rangle_G=\langle u,v\rangle_G$ directly.

Comment: You mean $<\rho(g)u,\rho(g)v>_G = |G|<u,v>_G$ right? Or should there be an additional sum?

Comment: No, that doesn't make any sense. If you plug $g=e$ into that equation you get $\langle u,v\rangle_G=|G|\langle u,v\rangle_G$ which, unless $|G|$ is $1$ modulo the characteristic, implies $\langle u,v\rangle_G=0$ for all $u,v$. That's hardly an inner product.

Comment: Oh.. yeah of course. So I calculate the following:
$\sum\nolimits_{g \in G} <\rho(g)u,\rho(g)v>_G = \sum\nolimits_{g \in G}\sum\nolimits_{g \in G}<\rho(g)\rho(g)u,\rho(g)\rho(g)v> = \sum\nolimits_{g \in G}\sum\nolimits_{g \in G} <\rho(g^2)u,\rho(g^2)v>$ Does that last step lead to anything? I feel like I'm close but I can't seem to close the deal... sorry for bothering you but can you help me one last time?
EDIT: OH! Since $G$ is a group $g^2$ is an element of $G$ again, so I'm still just summing over the whole group, which gives $|G|<u,v>_G$, correct ?

Comment: You can't sum over two different indices that have the same letter. It's like writing $\sum_i\sum_j ij$ as $\sum_i\sum_i ii$. More importantly: Why are you computing $\sum_{g\in G}\langle\rho(g)u,\rho(g)\rangle_G$ at all? Let's keep in our sights the goal we're after: to show  that $G$'s action is unitary with respect to $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_G$. This means that $\langle\rho(h)u,\rho(h)v\rangle_G=\langle u,v\rangle_G$ for all $h\in G$. *This* is what you're trying to show. (And BTW, no, as $g$ ranges over $G$, $g^2$ does not necessarily range over all of $G$; only the *squares* in $G$.)

Comment: Woops... alright let's try this again:

$<\rho(h)u,\rho(h)v>_G = \sum\nolimits_{g \in G}<\rho(h)\rho(g)u,\rho(h)\rho(g)v>_G =\sum\nolimits_{g \in G} <\rho(hg)u,\rho(hg)v>$ 
But now I'm still not summing over the whole of $G$, because $gh$ doesn't range over all $g \in G$ right?:/

Comment: Left-multiplication by any fixed element $h$ is a bijection from $G$ to itself. Its inverse map is left-multiplication by $h^{-1}$. (You want to grasp the elementary group theory facts very intuitively to know what you're doing in representation theory.)

Comment: *sigh* Okay, thanks a lot! Yeah them wanting us to do Representation Theory without having had a course in Group Theory seems super rushed... but now I gotta do what I gotta do. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to define a $G$-invariant inner product by using an initial inner product. So pick any basis for the space and let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be the inner product it induces. This is pretty arbitrary. Now define

$$\langle u,v\rangle_G:=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\langle\rho(g)u,\rho(g)v\rangle.$$

It is standard to put the normalization factor $\frac{1}{|G|}$ in front, though ultimately it isn't necessary. The reason is that if $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ was $G$-invariant to begin with then $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle=\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_G$, which is aesthetically pleasing. The task is then to show that $G$ acts by unitary transformations with respect to $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_G$, i.e.

$$\langle\rho(h)u,\rho(h)v\rangle_G=\langle u,v\rangle_G.$$

You need to do this by expanding the inner products (using its definition above), then employing the inherent symmetry in the situation (the summands are the exact same, only permuted).