# What about groups from non-orthogonal matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, representation-theory, polytopes

I am trying to characterize all finite groups which can be made from two
4D-real-matrix-represented generators.  Though matrix coefficients must be real
(I am avoiding complex coefficients since they effectively double the dimension to 8D),
matrix columns are generally not orthogonal (but, through a transformation, one matrix
could be considered orthogonal).

Given that the two matrices form a finite group, their determinants must be +1 or -1.

If columns were orthogonal for both matrices, I believe I would always be looking at one of the
[6 possible polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-polytope) (ignoring reflection-multiplied groups from lower-dimensional polytope groups, e.g., 2D cyclic groups which can be of any length).

Or, will I see more groups if I include non-orthogonal matrices?  Conversely, if I see one of the
6 possible polytopes, will the two matrices be simultaneously orthonormally-reducible?

Comment: Why the downvote?  Maybe I'm missing something obvious to you, but at least give me a hint...

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @Randall The title is unclear, but it was meant to draw attention to mathematicians/physicists always talking about "Special Orthogonal" SO(n) groups as if no one cares about non-orthogonal matrices, or as if they are equivalent somehow...are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a basic trick in the representation theory of finite (or more generally, compact) groups that allows you to assume your matrices are orthogonal.  Namely, given any finite subgroup $G\subseteq GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, you can always find an inner product which is preserved by each element of $G$ (so if you change to an orthonormal basis with respect to that inner product, $G$ will become a subgroup of the orthogonal group).  The trick is that any positive linear combination of inner products is an inner product, so let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be any inner product and define $$\langle x,y\rangle'=\sum_{g\in G}\langle gx,gy\rangle.$$  Then $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle'$ is an inner product, and is $G$-invariant because applying an element of $G$ will just permute the summands.

Comment: Surely this averaging technique has been explained on the site earlier. For example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/336096/11619).

Comment: Wow, good trick!  So, answers to my two questions are No and Yes.
By the way, is there a public database somewhere with 4D matrices for these
4D groups, e.g., for 600-cell?  It's easy to find coordinates for the vertices
online, but I can't find matrices.