# Orthogonality of cyclic finite group of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $M$ be a cyclic finite subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$.
Is it necessary for matrices $A$ from $M$ to be orthogonal?

Indeed, because $A^k=I$ for some $k$ we have determinant of real matrix $A$  equal to $-1$ or $1$.

But generally there are matrices with such determinant which are not orthogonal. However I can't find other example of $M$ where matrices are not orthogonal.

How to prove that $AA^T=I$ or to find counterexample?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I would prefer in the answer the condition that a group is cyclic be used ..

Comment: It suffices to look at finite subgroups (even compact ones). But anyway, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4180412/what-about-groups-from-non-orthogonal-matrices) is explaining that you may restrict to orthogonal matrices, but you could also use non-orthogonal ones, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A^k=I$ for some $k\ge1$ does not imply $AA^T=I.$

As a counterexample, you can take any non-orthogonal matrix $A$ such that $A^2=I,$ like
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2\\0&-1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Similarly, the matrix
$$B:=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\cos\frac{2\pi}k&-\sin\frac{2\pi}k\\\sin\frac{2\pi}k&\cos\frac{2\pi}k
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$
satisfies $B^k=I$ (and $\det B=1$) but is not orthogonal.

Comment: So it would be a subgroup consisting of only two elements $A$ and $I$. But what if there would be more elements in groups, especially when $A$ is not equal to $A^{-1}$? Is it possible similar counterexample with determinant equal to $1$?

Comment: @Widawensen Consider the companion matrices of those [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) with three or more nonzero terms. If their determinants are $-1$, negate their last columns.

Comment: @user1551 Very useful answer, thank you.  So it seems that such companion matrices are very illustrative  for this kind of problem.

Comment: @user1551 In conclusion,  can we say that such companion matrices are always appropriate as generators for constructing a cyclic finite groups?

Comment: @Anne. Probably a some typo  remains in your second formula. (it seems that the last matrix should be also in generalized form).

Comment: @Anne. From my calculations  general form of the last matrix [{{c + s, -2 s}, {s, c - s}}]

Comment: From mine as well, but I did not find it useful to mention it, and I forgot to delete a last matrix copied-pasted from my first example. Thanks to you, I just deleted it.

Comment: @Widawensen No. E.g. the characteristic polynomial of the $B$ in Anne’s answer is not a product of cyclotomic polynomials except for a few values of $k$.